# Rails User trying to follow 2 Events, but instead follows one event twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the progression of what we are trying to do and what is actually happening:

1. User creates Event with id=1
2. User creates Event with id=2
3. User clicks "Attend" for Event 1---> User is attending Event 1
4. User clicks "Attend" on Event 2 ---> User is not attending Event 2, but is attending Event 1 a second time

Any insight onto why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.

**User.rb model**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends, class_name:  "Friend", foreign_key: "follower_id",
    dependent:   :destroy

    has_many :fellows, class_name: "Friend", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

    has_many :following, through: :friends, source: :followed
    has_many :followers, through: :fellows, source: :follower

    has_many :relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "user_id"

    has_many :relations, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "event_id"

    has_many :coming, through: :relationships, source: :user
    has_many :going, through: :relations, source: :event

    has_attached_file :photo
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]


    def self.omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider 
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.dog_name = "A"
        user.dog_breed = "A"
        user.dog_gender = "Unknown"
        user.dog_age = "0"
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.save!
        end
    end

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :uid, presence: true
    validates_length_of :dog_name, minimum: 0, maximum: 30, message: 'cannot have more than 30 characters'
    validates_format_of :dog_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z-']+\z/, message: "can only contain letters, ' and -"
    validates_length_of :dog_breed, minimum: 0, maximum: 30, message: 'cannot have more than 30 characters'
        validates_format_of :dog_breed, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z-']+\z/, message: "can only contain letters, ' and -"

    # Follows a user.
    def follow(other_profile)
        friends.create(followed_id: other_profile.id)
    end

    # Unfollows a user.
    def unfollow(other_profile)
        friends.find_by(followed_id: other_profile.id).destroy
    end

    # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
    def following?(other_profile)
        following.include?(other_profile)
    end

    def coming(event)
        relationships.create(event_id: event.id)
    end

    def unattend(event)
        relationships.find_by(event_id: event.id).destroy
    end

    def attending?(event)
        going.include?(event)
    end
    # Profile will follow an event
end
```

**event.rb model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "user_id"

has_many :relations, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "event_id"

has_many :coming, through: :relationships, source: :user
has_many :going, through: :relations, source: :event

validates :event_name, presence: true
validates :place, presence: true

validates_length_of :event_name, minimum: 1, maximum: 30, message: "Event Name must be at least 1 character and less than 30 characters"
validates_length_of :place, minimum: 1, maximum: 50, message: "Event location must be at least 1 character and less than 50 characters"
#validates_format_of :event, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z0-9-']+\z/

def going(user)
    relations.create(user_id: user.id)
end

def uncome(user)
    relations.find_by(user_id: user.id).destroy
end

def coming?(user)
    coming.include?(user)
end
end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :requireLogin

    def requireLogin
        if session[:user_id] == nil
            redirect_to "/"
        end
    end

    def index
       @events = Event.all
    end

   def main
       @event = Event.find(params[:id])
       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
       @creator = User.find(@event.createdByID)
    end

   def new
       @event = Event.new
            @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
       @event.createdByID = @current_user.id
    end

   def coming
       @title = "coming"
       @event = Event.find([:id])
       @events = @event.coming.paginate(page: params[:page])
       render 'show'
    end

    def create
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        @event.createdByID = Rails.application.config.currUserID
        if @event.save
            redirect_to '/event'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
            redirect_to action: "show"
            # Handle a successful update.
            else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to(events_path)
    end

    private
    def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :place, :time_of)
    end
end
```

**Relationships controller**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        current_user.coming(event)
        redirect_to '/event'
    end

    def destroy
        event = Relationship.find(params[:id]).event
        current_user.unattend(event)
        redirect_to '/event'
    end

    def main
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

end
```

**_attend.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@current_user.relationships.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, @event.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Attend", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**_attend_form.html.erb**

```
<% unless current_user = nil %>
  <div id="attend_form">
  <% if @event.coming?(@current_user) %>
    <%= render 'leave' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'attend' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What action is the "Attend" button calling?  I don't see anything in the EventsController that would create the association.

Answer (score -1):

Where _attend_form.html.erb is rendered? What controller and action?

In RelationshipsController#main you have:

> @event = Event.find(params[**:id**])

But in create action it's:

> event = Event.find(params[**:event_id**])

Check that you pass correct param for event id in main action.